# HP ALM C# REST set attachment for requirement

Tags: c#, rest, hp-alm

I've seen many different 'answers' to this, none of them complete.  This is my current code for my upload function.  It should be complete enough for discussion.  I'm getting a (500) error when attempting to upload a .png file.  The .png file gets consumed by the formbytes stream, but when it gets to the actual request on the last line, it throws the error.  HELP!

```
public void Upload(string uri, string filePath)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
        string fileType = fi.Extension.Replace(".", "");
        string slug = fi.Name.Replace(fi.Extension, "");
        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\" filename=\"{0}\";\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundarybytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        request.Accept = "application/json";

        if (cookies != null)
        {
        // cookies is a cookie container populated by another process, works for creating ALM requirements
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        }

        request.Headers.Add("slug", slug);

        string formitem = "";
        byte[] formbytes = null;
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
                formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, Path.GetFileName(filePath));
                formbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
                requestStream.Write(formbytes, 0, formbytes.Length);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
                int bytesLeft = 0;

                while ((bytesLeft = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesLeft);
                }

            }
        }
            //request.Headers.Add(formbytes);

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) { }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I had to check-out the requirement to add the attachment.  It's a simple post, with no body needed, to :

/rest/domains/[domain]/projects/[project]/requirements/[entityId]/versions/check-out

and you can check-in, also no body needed:

/rest/domains/[domain]/projects/[project]/requirements/[entityId]/versions/check-out